# An encoding that maps the values of the function to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, mapping

I have to create an encoding function that takes in numbers in list and returns the following:

- `encode(0)` should return `[]` i.e. 0 maps done to the list
- `encode(x+1)` should return `[encode(x),[encode(x)]]` i.e. x+1 maps to the list containing encode(x) (i.e. [encode(x)]) and encode(x)

if there is any confusion please lemme know!

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

The function is pretty much as you have described it:

```
def encode(i):
    if i == 0:
        return []
    else:
        r=encode(i-1)
        return [r,[r]]
```